# Algebra: Linear Equations & Graphs. A doubt with Slope - intercept form & Point - slope form.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Slope - intercept form : `y = mx + b`

Point - slope form :

`m (x - a) = y - b
mx - ma = y - b
y = mx - ma + b`

As `ma` & `b` are constants, `b - ma = c`

`y = mx + c`

It seems like the two forms are the same. Then why name them different ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They’re written in different forms but equivalent

Comment: I see, Is there any use to writing them in different forms ?

Comment: With one form you can see the intercept right away; with another you can see a point on the line right away

Comment: Oh.. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several forms for a [linear equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation), including $ax+by=0$, $y=mx+b$, $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$, and $\frac x {x_0} + \frac y {y_0} = 1,$ and the two-point form.  They are all equivalent.  Particular forms are useful for seeing particular parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much for further explanation! :)